# How to show Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Prove that if $X$ has a dense finite subset, then $X$ itself is finite?

Tags: metric-spaces

> Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Prove that if $X$ has a dense finite
> subset, then $X$ itself is finite.

My attempt: if possible, $X$ is infinite and $A$ be a finite dense subset of $X$. Now for any point $x$ in $X$,any neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point from $A$. Since $X$ contains infinite number if points and $A$ is finite there will be some contradiction which is not coming in my mind. Please I need help.

Comment: Let $x\in X$. For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $a_n\in B(x,\frac{1}{n})\cap A$. What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't far off. If $A$ is a subset of the metric space $X$ that is dense and finite, then $A = X$. To see this assume (for a contradiction) that $A$ a proper finite dense subset of the metric space $X$ and let $x \in X \setminus A$.  As $x \not\in A$, $d(x, a) > 0$ for every $a \in A$. But then if we take $\varepsilon = \frac{\min_{a\in A}d(x, a)}{2}$ (which is well-defined and positive because $A$ is finite), there is no element $a \in A$ with $d(x, a) < \varepsilon$, so $A$ is not dense.